# Spring boot server errors

Tags: spring, tomcat, web, server

So I'm new to spring boot and I have a problem with the server, I think the code is just fine.
So here is my classes:

This is my main class
[image: This is my main class]

Controller class
[image: Controller class]

HTML Page
[image: HTML PAGE]

This is what I get when I click on localhost:8181/
[image: this is what i get when i click on localhost:8181/]

It says that I have to open a session and
when I click on cancel it shows this: 
[image: the server error]

Comment: Whoever downvote the question could have added a comment explaining why. No one learns anything by just being negative, without an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**it worked by doing this :**

- the username field :user
- the password field : you'll find it in the console -->

  - Using generated security password: ..........

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error is well described, as you don't have a "error" page mapped, you're sended to the default error page.
Maybe you console is showing something more usefull, you should give a look at that and use that as your question.
I don't know why you are autowiring the Repositories in your Application. If you are using Spring Data Rest it's not needed.
Also, a recommendation  is that you post your code here, not images, describing what were you plan to do. Are you just trying to open an index page with some label? So why all the Repo? Try to start with a cleaner project, just with the classes that are really needed (first things first). After that, add one Entity/Repo at the time.
Maybe this is not the answer you are looking for, but I strongly recommend you get some Spring Boot tutorial for beginners (there are so many!), and do a more specific question here.

Comment: thanks , so I found that errors like this happen because of the package root that is not the same as the springbootapplication but what i'm showing here is that my package root is the same ,  and yes i'm trying to open an index page with some label for now , for testing... all the repo i'll need them later but for now i wanna be sure that it works with a simple labels before doing something else

Comment: I believe your console could be showing the "real" error. The white page error is just a default error of Spring.

Comment: what the console shows : Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.demo.web.BanqueController.index() .. i saw that this error is because of the package root but mine are correct

Comment: Try to remove all the Repositories from your application class. Only the main method is needed. Also, remove the implements CommandLineRunner and make it extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter.